# cumulative distribution function of $Z:=\min(X,Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let be $X,Y$ two independent discrete random variables and $Z:=\min(X,Y)$. Calculate the cumulative distribution function of $Z$.

**My approach:**

Let be $F_X$ and $F_Y$ the cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

$$\begin{align*}
&P(Z\leq k)=P(\min(X,Y)\leq k)\\
&=P(X\leq k, Y\geq k)+P(X>k,Y\leq k)+P(X<k,Y<k)\\
&=F_X(k)(1-F_Y(k-1))+(1-F_X(k))F_Y(k)+F_X(k-1)F_Y(k-1)\\
&=F_X(k)-F_X(k)F_Y(k-1)+F_Y(k)-F_Y(k)F_X(k)+F_X(k-1)F_Y(k-1)\\
&=F_X(k)+F_Y(k)-F_Y(k)F_X(k)-F_Y(k-1)(F_X(k)-F_X(k-1))\\
&=F_X(k)+F_Y(k)-F_Y(k)F_X(k)-F_Y(k-1)P(X=k)
\end{align*}$$

However a quick google search delivers $F_Z(k)=F_X(k)+F_Y(k)-F_Y(k)F_X(k)$.

Where is my mistake? (I am not interested in an alternative approach)

PS: I know that similar questions have been asked many times before but I would like to know where my error is.

Comment: Note that the event $\{X=k, Y<k\} \subset \{Z \le k\}$ is not being considered.

Comment: Be careful with $<$ and $\leq$, $>$ and $\geq $.

Comment: Also, performing the calculations with $P(Z>k)$ is much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first step you said that

$$ min(X,Y) \leq k \iff (X \leq k, Y \geq k)\, \cup \, (X>k,Y\leq k) \,\cup\, (X<k,Y<k) $$

However this does not account for the case where $X = k$ and $Y < k$, so it is incorrect.

A possible correction is

$$ min(X,Y) \leq k \iff (X \leq k, Y > k) \, \cup \, (Y \leq k)$$ both sets are disjoint, so it is still easy to calculate probabilities.